# Does there exist linear map with required properties?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Does there exist a non zero linear map $T: \mathbb {R}^5 \to \mathbb{R}^5$ such that ker$(T) \cap W \neq \{0\}$ for every $4$ dimesional subspace $W$ of $V$?

I think that such map exist but don't know how to construct. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key of the answer is this identity

$$\dim(U+W)=\dim U+\dim W-\dim(U\cap W)$$
so with $U=\ker T$ so we see that if we construct $T$ such that $\dim\ker T\ge2$ and since $\dim(\ker T+W)\le \dim V=5$ then we get $\dim(\ker T\cap W)>0$ hence $\ker T\cap W\ne\{0\}$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $T[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4] = x_0$. Then $\dim\ker T = 4$. If for some $W$, $W \cap \ker T = \{\mathbf 0\}$, then the direct sum $W \oplus \ker T$ must have dimension $8$, but it is contained in a $5$-dimensional space. Thus such $W$ cannot exist.

Comment: Ahh i see..Thank you! Could you please say why did you think of this example?

Comment: @Dontknowanything The idea is to max out $\dim\ker T$ and see what happens.